# SQL count number of groups

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012

I have a table with pallets, items, item quantity:

```
pallet | item | qty
-------------------
  1        1     2
  1        2     4
  2        3     2
  2        5     3
  3        4     4
```

I need to find count(pallet), count(item), sum(qty)

```
count(pallets) | count(items) | sum(qty)
----------------------------------------
      3                5           15
```

I can get the sum(qty) and count(item) with

```
select count(0) as totalItems, sum(qty) as total from table
```

Is there a way to get the number of pallets without a sub-query?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, use `DISTINCT`

```
select count(distinct pallet) as pallets,
       sum(qty) as total, 
       count(*) as totalItems 
from your_table
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought it was something like that  but I couldn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 2):

Simply use Distinct to avoid duplicate records to be count.

```
count(Distinct pallet)
```

Your query like this

```
select 
      count(distinct pallet) as pallets,
      sum(qty) as Total, 
      count(item) AS [Total Items]
```

it will give output AS :

[image: it will give output AS :]